# Are OpenCV Hough Circles sorted?

Tags: opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I want to use OpenCV Hough Circles' implementation, but I have a question: 
**the circles that this function returns are already sorted by vote?**

Since Hough transform is based on a voting mechanism, I want to know if this circles are return in order from the most voted to the least voted, or in a random order.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are sorted according to the vote in the accumulator in descending order.

You'll notice that in the function that actually computes the hough transform `icvHoughCirclesGradient` inside `hough.cpp`, where `icvHoughSortDescent32s( &sort_buf[0], center_count, adata );` is called on the buffer containing the votes.

---

Note that ([source](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3363)) the centers are sorted according to the highest accumulated values based on circle centers with the highest vote from surrounding edge pixels, and not according to the number of supporting radius pixels. This make sense, since bigger circles would have higher support then.